# Web Inspector network tab shows Laravel resonse in two different colors: red and black

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using laravel 5.5. When I send response back from the controller in the console the response has been split into two different colors, red and black. when I loop through the response it only shows me those data which is red color, however, for the black it shows undefined in my view.

One more things friends, I have already used the Response facades in my controller.I have never encountered such error before while using laravel. This is my first time to face such type of error.

I have attached an image of my console section of my browse. Thank you very much.

```
**My Route:**
Route::post('/orders/change',[
            'uses'=> 'ProductController@change',
             'as'  => 'order.change'
        ]);

**My Ajax code:** 
$("#sidebar_list li>a").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var clickk  = $(this).attr('id');
            var clickk  = $(this).attr('id');
            var clickk  = $(this).attr('id');
            var clickk  = $(this).attr('id');
            var url_change = "{{ route('order.change') }}";
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: url_change,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {clickk:clickk},
                success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                var html;
                data = data.data;
                var numOfCols = 6;
                var rowCount = 0;
                var bootstrapColWidth = 12 / numOfCols;
                $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                    var id = obj.id;
                    var name = obj.name;
                    html +='<div class="row" >';

                                html += '<a href="#" class="table-id" data-ids = "'+obj.id+'">';
                                    html +='<div class="col-md-'+bootstrapColWidth+'">';
                                        html +='<div class="thumbnail back" style=" height:70px; text-align: center;">'+name;

                                        html +='</div>';
                                    html +='</div>';
                                html +='</a>';
                            rowCount++;
                        if (rowCount % numOfCols == 0){
                         html+='</div><div class="row">';
                        }

                    });  

                     html +='</div>';
                $('#panel-name').html(html);
                }
             });   
        });


**Controller Code:**    
public function change(Request $request){
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $clickk = $request->get('clickk');

              return  $result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM slots WHERE slot_type
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmcAb.png)

So what is the reason please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I can see this being duplicated four times - var clickk  = $(this).attr('id');. I am not sure that it would solve your issue...

Comment: no thats not the issue because i have checked it in my controller which get unique values for the type of the link clicked.Thanks for reply